# Duda al validar CheckBox que cree dinamicamente

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, checkbox

Tengo un proyecto en Xamarin y mediante este código, genero dinamicamente mas de un CheckBox

```
if (Lista != null && Lista.Count > 0)
{
    LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MatchParent, LayoutParams.WrapContent);

    foreach (var f in Lista)
    {
        CheckBox chProducto = new CheckBox(this);
        chProducto.Text = f.Concepto + " - $ " + f.Importe.ToString();
        chProducto.CheckedChange += chProducto_Checked;

        linLayBody.AddView(chProducto, lp);
    }
}
```

Es decir que dada una lista, voy creando un CheckBox (chProducto) por cada elemento de la lista, pero luego quiero validar cuales fueron los CheckBox que fueron "marcados" y me quede trabado por no saber como continuar ya que la cantidad de CheckBox que vaya a agregar nunca es fija... en algun momento pueden ser 2 y en otro momento pueden ser 10...

Alguien podría ayudarme a continuar?

Gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La forma mas facil de hacer esto (que no es la unica) es tener una lista (o una coleccion, o un array, o lo que te resulte mas simple) que guarde los objetos que estas agregando a la view (esto es para evitar recorrer la view).

Entonces tendrias los objetos en la view y tambien en tu array. Luego lo unico que tienes que hacer es recorrer ese array y chequear lo que necesites de cada uno.

Comment: funcionó correctamente... gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que crees un evento de click de checkbox y que se lo añadas dinamicamente a cada checkbox que crees.
Create tambien una lista de checkbox (lCheck)
en el evento de click haces que se añada a lCheck el propio checkbox en el que haces click
Luego recorres lCheck filtrando por Check=true y tendras todos los checks marcados